# Vuejs Render function - Emit child component events in parent

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vuetify.js

I'm having a requirement to have custom drag and drop functionality with Vuetify treeview. It works with little modification in the treeview code, but the draggable events are not being forwarded.

using Vuedraggable, added the below code in render function

```
genChildrenWrapper() {
  if (!this.isOpen || !this.children) return null;

  const children = [this.children.map(this.genChild)];

  return this.$createElement(
    "draggable",
    {
      staticClass: "v-treeview-node__children",
      attrs: {
        group: "treeview"
      }
    },
    children
  );
},
```

Comment: Welcome.  Please post some code.

Comment: Please show your code implementation, so we can see where the problem might be.

Comment: Added code implementation.